# String Class Weird Behavior

Tags: c++, string, firebase, http, arduino

I'm new to Arduino and C++, and I'm working on an Arduino project for school. I have a Firebase Cloud Function and I want to call if from the Arduino. I start a connection with the server and give it a query:

```
const String query = "QUERY";
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(client.remoteIP());
  // Make an HTTP request:
  client.println(query);
  client.println("Host: SERVER-HOST-NAME");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();
}
```

Now this works very fine if the query string was declared as one piece:

```
String query = String("GET /cloudFunctionName?dataThatShouldBeVariable=FixedData HTTP/1.1");
```

Example:

```
String query = String("GET /updateDatabase?temp=10 HTTP/1.1");
```

When using the method above the cloud function triggers and the database gets updated. But I can't use it in production because I have some variable data so what I did was:

```
String query = String("GET /cloudFunctionName?dataThatShouldBeVariable=" + String(VariableData) + " HTTP/1.1");
```

Example:

```
String query = String("GET /updateDatabase?temp=" + String(10) + " HTTP/1.1");
```

Now when I print the results of the two strings I get  the same result, but when using the second method the cloud function doesn't get triggered and the database doesn't get updated.

I believe that the problem is with the query variable not with the server or the hardware but I couldn't find an answer. I've been working on this for hours and I really got mad and I don't know what to do. **Please tell me what is the problem and how to fix it.**

Comment: What is `FixedData`? Is it valid string for a url query? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've added the real code.

Comment: well, it was just a guess. I'll delete the comment as it just adds noise

Comment: @user463035818 then what do you think I should do?

Comment: you should not listen to ppl that dont know what they are talking about :P. Sorry, I really dont know what `String` is, I would probably just do some rtfm, and use a debugger to inspect the string before using it for the next step

Comment: Here is the doc I saw: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

Comment: I find the Arduino doc hard to read. It's not obvious that you can do `char* + String(10)`. What if you try: `String query = String("GET /updateDatabase?temp=") + String(10) + String(" HTTP/1.1");`?

Comment: Can/does your http server log the incoming request, so that you can see how your non-working request compares to the working one (and/or can you just log the query on this side)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I actually did it but did't work too.

Comment: @PhilM it does log queries coming when using the first method, but it doesn't log anything when using the second method.